# web api, como fazer esse login de forma correta?

Tags: web-service, api, xamarin-forms

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que é uma versão resumida de um sistema web, esse sistema foi desenvolvido em PHP. Para o aplicativo, estou desenvolvendo em xamarin forms, no entanto via web api estou tentando fazer a tela de login, mas ao inserir qualquer login ou senha ele está logando, e isso não poderia acontecer, deveria logar apenas ao inserir os dados de usuario salvo no banco de dados. Abaixo o meu código:

**LoginPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class LoginPage : TabbedPage
    {

        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

        }

        protected async void BtnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailEntry.Text))
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Erro", "Digite um nome de usuário válido", "Aceitar");
                emailEntry.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(senhaEntry.Text))
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Erro", "Digite uma senha", "Aceitar");
                emailEntry.Focus();
                return;
            }
            this.logar();


            App.Current.MainPage = new MainPageRoot();
        }

        private async void logar()
        {
            waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
            var loginRequest = new LoginRequest
            {
                Usuario = emailEntry.Text,
                Senha = senhaEntry.Text,
            };
            var JsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginRequest);
            var httpContent = new StringContent(JsonRequest);
            var resp = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://ativoproject.ebasesistemas.com.br");
                var url = "http://ativoproject.ebasesistemas.com.br/login.php";
                var result = await client.PostAsync(url, httpContent);

                if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Erro", "Usuario ou senha incorretos", "Aceitar");
                    waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
                    return;
                }

                resp = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Erro", ex.Message, "Aceitar");
                waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
                return;

            }

            var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Colaborador>(resp);
            waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
            await DisplayAlert("Bem vindo","vc esta logado", "Aceitar");
        }
    }
```

**Colaborador.cs**

```
 public class Colaborador
    {
        public int ColaboradorID { get; set; }

        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public bool Inativo { get; set; }
    }
```

**LoginRequest.cs**

```
class LoginRequest
    {
        public string Usuario { get; set; }
        public string Senha { get; set; }
    }
```

E esse aqui é o link do sistema na web: http://ativoproject.ebasesistemas.com.br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geralmente a propriedade testada em `result.IsSuccessStatusCode` na verdade diz respeito à comunicação em si, se houve ou não sucesso no envio da requisição.

Se falhar, beleza, você precisa informar ao usuário que não conseguiu se comunicar com o servidor. Mas se conseguiu comunicar com o servidor (como parece ser o caso), você precisa fazer uma segunda etapa de verificação, analisando o conteúdo da resposta, que estaria sinalizado  a autenticação ou não ( através de mensagem ou um código) de acordo com suas regras de negócio (e o contrato da API que você está consumindo) informando se a autenticação foi feita ou não.

Essas informações devem estar disponíveis na propriedade `result.Content.Result`.

No seu caso, você está desserializando para um objeto do tipo `Colaborador` em `var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Colaborador>(resp);`. Provavelmente é uma estratégia onde considera sucesso se vem um `Colaborador` válido e, se não vem, significa que não autenticou (mas também você não sabe o motivo, pode ser a senha errada, pode ser que o usuário esteja bloqueado, pode ser que o usuário não exista...).

Sugiro você consultar o contrato da sua api ou depurar o resultado dessa propriedade de retorno para alguns cenários para saber como tratar.

Espero que isso ajude.

Comment: Eu entendi mais ou menos, pois ainda sou um principiante nessa linguagem, tu conseguiria me mostrar um exemplo disso que está dizendo aplicado no meu contexto?

Comment: @WPfan Para mostrar no seu cenário, eu precisaria conhecer a estrutura da resposta que você recebe do webservice para tratar o que estaríamos esperando, mas eu vou tentar incluir um exemplo na resposta.